# Integrate webapp

Tags: web-applications, integration, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

hey  I am trying to integrate agora into my webapp. I want it to be one to one. I am not being able to do it. Third person can still join in and then the quality drops drastically. Can anyone help me fix it

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve the one to one video call, you can use the Agora RTM SDK. To do that, before a user joins the RTC channel (video call channel), he should also join the RTM channel with the same channel name as the one used for video call. Then you can use “getMembers” method in RTM SDK to retrieve a list of users in that channel. If there are already 2 users in this channel, this user should be blocked from joining in the channel.

“getMembers” api: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_cpp/classagora_1_1rtm_1_1_i_channel.html#a3f9c943059ac48a568c81798da38c3cb